# What's the purpose of the different kinds of TensorFlow SignatureDefs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

It seems like the Predict SignatureDef encompasses all the functionality of the Classification and Regression SignatureDefs. When would there be an advantage to using Classification or Regression SignatureDefs rather than just using Predict for everything? We're looking to keep complexity down in our production environment, and if it's possible to use just Predict SignatureDefs in all cases, that would seem like a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see on the documentation (https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/signature_defs) it seems the "Classify" and "Regress" **SigDefs try to force a simple and consistent interface for the simple cases (classify and regress),** respectively, "inputs"-->"classes+scores" and "inputs"->"outputs". There seems to be an added benefit that the "Classify" and "Regress" SigDefs dont require a serving function to be constructed as part of the model export function.

Also from the docs, it seems the Predict SigDef allows a more generic interface with the benefit of being able to swap in and out models. From the docs:

> Predict SignatureDefs enable portability across models. This means
>   that you can swap in different SavedModels, possibly with different
>   underlying Tensor names (e.g. instead of x:0 perhaps you have a new
>   alternate model with a Tensor z:0), while your clients can stay online
>   continuously querying the old and new versions of this model without
>   client-side changes.
>
> Predict SignatureDefs also allow you to add optional additional
>   Tensors to the outputs, that you can explicitly query. Let's say that
>   in addition to the output key below of scores, you also wanted to
>   fetch a pooling layer for debugging or other purposes.

***However*** the docs dont explain, aside from the minor benefit of not having to export a serving function, why one wouldn't just use the Predict SigDef for everything since it appears to be a superset with plenty of upside. I'd love to see a definitive answer on this, as the benefits of the specialized functions (classify, regress) seem quite minimal.

Answer (score 0):

The differences I've seen so far are...

1) If utilizing the tf.feature_column.indicator_column wrapping the tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_* in a DNNClassifier model, when you query the [tensorflow server](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/), I've had problems with the Predict API sometimes not being able to parse/map string inputs according to the vocabulary file/list. On the other hand, the Classify API properly mapped strings to their index (categorical_column) on the vocabulary, and then to the one-hot/multi-hot (indicator_column), and provided (what seems to be) the correct classification response to the query.

2) The response format of [[class, score],[class,score],....] for Classify API vs [class[], score[]] for Predict API. One or the other may be preferable if you need to parse the data in some way afterwards.

TLDR; With indicator_column wrapped in categorical_column_with_vocabulary_*, I've experienced issues with the vocabulary mapping when serving with Predict API. So, using Classify API.